# Angular 4 / Reactive form and json as select value

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form created in component:

```
this.details = this.FormBuilder.group({
  status: {}
});
```

Then in my template I have:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status of formValues?.status" [ngValue]="status">{{status.name}} {{status.description}}</option>
</select>
```

and OnChanges called:

```
  this.details.setValue({
    status: this.data.status
  });
```

The idea is, that I have a single select, that has to have an object as a value. I can't make status as a nested formGroup, since it would have to be spitted into 3 formControls. Everything works fine, despite the setValue. My select is not getting the default data. However, when I change option in select, form model updates correctly.

Any ideas :)?

Answer (score 0):

First off the syntax for option is:
`<option *ngFor="let entry of entries" [value]="entry">{{entry}}</option>`
So `value` instead of `ngValue`. Secondly u need to use two way data biding right now the values are only emited from template to model and not the other way.
So add `[(ngModel)]` to your `select`

`<select [(ngModel)]=status...`>

One more thing I suggested changing the name in form builder so you don't have a clash in the ngFor loop `status:{}` and `*ngFor="let status of formValues?.status`

Usage example with ngModel and select from official docs (link below):

> `<div class="form-group">
>     <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
>     <select class="form-control"  id="power"
>             required
>             [(ngModel)]="model.power" name="power">
>       <option *ngFor="let pow of powers" [value]="pow">{{pow}}</option>
>     </select>
>   </div>`

[1] https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: 1. Value of the select is an object, when I use [value] it just shows [object Object], that is why I use [ngValue]. 2. I cant use ng-model, since I am using reactive form, not a template driven one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the component:

```
compareFn(c1: StatusModel, c2: StatusModel): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
}
```

instead of "StatusModel", insert the form status model.
and add a binding in the template:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="status"
       [compareWith]="compareFn"<!-- binding -->
    <option *ngFor="let status of formValues?.status" 
            [ngValue]="status">
        {{status.name}} {{status.description}}
    </option>
</select>
```